# Matlab Easily Graphing Data With Conditions

Tags: matlab, graph, histogram

I have a survey dataset with several categories I'd like to condition on to make demographic comparisons. For example, the dataset has seven columns for race either populated with a string (e.g. Asian), or a blank cell. Other columns include ratings from 0 to 10, yes or no questions, etc.

What is the most efficient way to graph several histograms based on a race, time of submission, or response to another question?

TL:DR; how do I quickly graph data conditioned on other arrays/columns?

Comment: Is your dataset saved in a database ? Maybe then it is best to perform conditions on the database directly. See for instance: http://fr.mathworks.com/help/database/run-sql-query.htm

Comment: It's raw CSV or xlsx format